# In C# what is lifetime or lifespan of constant variable?

Tags: c#, const

In C# if i declare a constant variable is any memory allocated to it as it acts as a compile time replacement? How long is the variable's life?

Comment: Is it a primitive? Or object?

Comment: @MichaelT If I recall, `const` can only be applied to strings & numerical values, and not objects. Those have to be qualified with `static readonly`.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII With one exception: you can do `const SomeReferenceType constField = null;`.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII ahh - please pardon my java-ness for that where we've only got `final` (with its multitude of meanings).

Answer (score 5):

Literal `const`s are compile time replacements. Section 14.16 in the spec I have handy:

> A constant expression is an expression that shall be fully evaluated at compile-time.

Comment: ok...so does it get a memory allocated to it?
and is it alive as long the application is running?

Comment: It depends. `public const double pi = 3.14` will simply replace anywhere `pi` is referenced with the constant `3.14`. The constant itself will be part of the bytecode and thus takes up space (in the compiled CIL), but no more than literally putting "3.14" everywhere instead of "pi". And since it lives in bytecode, it does not _ever_ live, per se.

Answer (score 0):

No memory is allocated since the value is put directly into code.  The compiler places the constant in the assembly metadata, so the lifetime of the constant is the lifetime of the assembly it's in.

Comment: even i thought so and searched for the same over the net...but could not be sure...